# Does cruise control works with Apache kafka 3.3.1

Tags: apache-kafka, cruisecontrol

Getting 0 metrics collected from 0 brokers when kafka is upgraded from 2.8.1 to 3.3.1

Can Someone help here

Comment: Wait for an answer https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control/issues/1954

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because github issues should be used for product questions